# How to exclude a specific widget ( QToolTip ) from the stylesheet applied on the parent

Tags: c++, qt, parent-child, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I have a widget class derived from QWidget. Earlier, there was a stylesheet applied on it, to set the font size of all the string in the widget

```
setStyleSheet( QString( "font-size: %1px;" ).arg( fontSize ) );
```

This was resulting in all the strings in the widget to have a specific font size.
But I would like to have the tooltips in the widget to have the default font style.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I found a similar question in Qt Centre: [Setting stylesheet for "almost" all widgets](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/12828-Setting-stylesheet-for-quot-almost-quot-all-widgets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the first font size to all widgets with the `*` selector, and then the second font size to `QToolTip` objects with type selector:

```
setStyleSheet("*{font-size: 20px;} QToolTip{ font-size: 8pt; }");
```